# Node js - Rest API - file upload and save

Tags: node.js

I have 2 use cases,

1. Serve files using http in Node js - I am able to achieve this using express 
   app.use(express.static('files')).
2. Accept files as byte array in request body and store them in a directory. The content in the byte array would be a word document.

I am trying to find a way to convert the byte array to word document in Node JS.
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated?

Note: I am not using multipart form upload in express. The word document would be sent in http request body.